# Autowire jdbcTemplate in ObjectMother for a junit 4 integration test

Tags: java, integration-testing, junit4, autowired, jdbctemplate

I was wondering if I can somehow autowire jdbcTemplate in the [ObjectMother](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ObjectMother.html) for a junit 4 integration Test.

The purpose of the test is to test that if you attach a document to an employee, you cannot attach afterwards a document with the same name.
For that I made an EmployeeMother that has a method that creates an Employee and a method that inserts it, using jdbcTemplate. If I try to autowire the jdbcTemplate in EmployeeMother it is null(test returns NPE on the first update). It seems I only have access to the applicationContexts from the test itself.

Currently I set it from the test itself, but I would like not to, because I will create more ObjectMothers for different objects and would like not to set the jdbcTemplate for all of them.

Here are the two classes (I deleted the company name from the package and imports):

**EmployeeMother**:

```
    package com.domain.objMother;

    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

    import com.domain.vo.Company;
    import com.domain.vo.Contact;
    import com.domain.vo.Employee;
    import com.domain.vo.Identification;
    import com.domain.vo.Role;

    public class EmployeeMother {
        private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

        protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
        private Employee empJohnDoe;

        /**
         * 
         * @return returns an admin user with username djohn
         */
        public Employee getEmpJohnDoe() {
            empJohnDoe = new Employee();
            empJohnDoe.setUserName("djohn");

            Role role = new Role();
            //as only the id of the role is not nullable I set it as 1 = admin
            role.setId(new Long(1));
            empJohnDoe.setRole(role);
            empJohnDoe.setCompany(new Company());

            Identification identity = new Identification();
            identity.setFirstName("John");
            identity.setLastName("Doe");
            identity.setContact(new Contact());
            empJohnDoe.setIdentity(identity);

            return empJohnDoe;
        }

        public void setEmpJohnDoe(Employee empJohnDoe) {
            this.empJohnDoe = empJohnDoe;
        }

        /**
         * Important! this insert does not cover some details of the Employee:
         * It inserts null in the following columns:
         * pswd,
         * image,
         * cnt_id, - should be a list of associated contacts
         * salt,
         * is_active,
         * default_work_hours
         * The insert in TAB_IDENTIFICATIONS triggers TRIG_IDNT that inserts stuff in an audit table
         * For it to work we need to register a logged user
         * That's why we call PAC_SECURITY.PRO_SETCTX('emp_user_name','adminUserName'); (i used an admin)
         * I preferred doing this rather than inserting djohn in TAB_EMPLOYEES, 
         * registering djohn as logged then inserting an identity in TAB_IDENTIFICATIONS
         * and then updating djohn with the new identity
         * @param emp - Employee to be inserted
         */
        public void insert(Employee emp){
            jdbcTemplate.update("call PAC_SECURITY.PRO_SETCTX('emp_user_name','adminUserName')");

            Long identityId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select max(ti.ID)+1 from tab_identifications ti", Long.class);
            emp.getIdentity().setId(identityId);

            jdbcTemplate.update(""+
                "   insert into tab_identifications ("+
                "       id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, cnp, ci_char, ci_number, birth_date, invalidity,"+
                "       cas_name, ci_issue_date, ci_issuer, cnt_id"+
                "   )" +
                "   values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                new Object[]{emp.getIdentity().getId(), emp.getIdentity().getFirstName(), emp.getIdentity().getMiddleName(),
                             emp.getIdentity().getLastName(), emp.getIdentity().getCnp(), emp.getIdentity().getIdCardSerial(),
                             emp.getIdentity().getIdCardNumber(), emp.getIdentity().getBirthDate(), 
                             emp.getIdentity().getInvalidity(), emp.getIdentity().getCAS(), emp.getIdentity().getCiIssueDate(),
                             emp.getIdentity().getCiIssuer(), emp.getIdentity().getContact().getId()}
            );      

            Long id = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select max(te.ID)+1 from tab_employees te", Long.class);
            emp.setId(id);
            jdbcTemplate.update(""+
                "   insert into tab_employees (id, user_name, code, pswd, idnt_id, role_id, comp_id, image, "+
                "       hire_date, cnt_id, salt, is_expired, is_active, default_work_hours "+
                "   )" +
                "   values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                new Object[]{emp.getId(), emp.getUserName(), emp.getCode(), null, emp.getIdentity().getId(),
                             emp.getRole().getId(), emp.getCompany().getId(), null, emp.getHireDate(),
                             null, null, emp.getIsExpired(), null, null
                }
            );
        }

        public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
            return jdbcTemplate;
        }

        public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        }
    }
```

**HomeEmployeeServiceImplIntegrationTest:**

```
    package com.employee.service.impl;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

    import com.domain.vo.Document;
    import com.domain.vo.Employee;
    import com.domain.objMother.EmployeeMother;
    import com.employee.service.HomeEmployeeService;
    import com.util.annotations.TransactionalDevTest;

    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @TransactionalDevTest
    public class HomeEmployeeServiceImplIntegrationTest {

        @Autowired
        protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        @Autowired
        HomeEmployeeService homeEmployeeService;

        EmployeeMother empMother = new EmployeeMother();
        Employee empJohnDoe;

        @Before
        public void beforeEachTest() throws Exception {
            empMother.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
            empJohnDoe = empMother.getEmpJohnDoe();
            empMother.insert(empJohnDoe);
        }

        /**
         * You should not be able to add a document with the same name
         * <code>uploadDocument</code> should not insert the document if it has the same name 
         */
         @Test
         public void shouldNotBeAbleToAddSameDoc(){
             Document doc = new Document();
             Long id = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select max(td.ID)+1 from tab_documents td", Long.class);
             doc.setId(id);
             doc.setFileName("SameOldDocument");

             homeEmployeeService.uploadDocument(empJohnDoe.getIdentity(), doc);

             id = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select max(td.ID)+1 from tab_documents td", Long.class);
             doc.setId(id);
             homeEmployeeService.uploadDocument(empJohnDoe.getIdentity(), doc);

             Long docNo = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(id) from tab_documents td where doc_file_name = '" + doc.getFileName() + "'", Long.class);

             if(docNo.compareTo(new Long(2)) == 0){
                 assertEquals("I was able to add a document twice with the same name!", new Long(1), docNo);
             }
             else{
                 assertEquals("Something went wrong when adding two documents with the same name! The document should be added once or twice, but the result is different!", new Long(1), docNo);
             }
        }
```

TransactionalDevTest is where I define all the applicationContexts used.
The code above works, but I would like to separate EmployeeMother's code and add IdentificationMother and probably DocumentMother each with it's object and insert. I would also like not to set jdbcTemplate for each ObjectMother (things can become ambiguous, some setting jdbcTemplate from the test, some setting it from another ObjectMother).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was helped by a collegue and this is what I did:

I made an annotation for ObjectMothers:

```
package com.util.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ObjectMother {}
```

I added this annotation to my EmployeeMother:

```
@ObjectMother
public class EmployeeMother {
```

and autowired my jdbcTemplate in EmployeeMother (also deleted the getter and setter)

```
@Autowired
protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

I added to an applicationContext:

The xmlns:

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
```

with schema location

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
```

and

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.domain.objMother">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="com.util.annotations.ObjectMother"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

This searches all classes annotated with ObjectMother and adds them to the applicationContext (so that you don't have to add them all one by one).

And finnaly I used EmployeeMother autowired in HomeEmployeeServiceImplIntegrationTest and deleted any reference to jdbcTemplate from EmployeeMother in the same class:

```
@Autowired
EmployeeMother empMother;
```

Final classes:

**EmployeeMother:**

```
    package com.domain.objMother;

    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

    import com.domain.vo.Company;
    import com.domain.vo.Contact;
    import com.domain.vo.Employee;
    import com.domain.vo.Identification;
    import com.domain.vo.Role;
    import com.util.annotations.ObjectMother;

    @ObjectMother
    public class EmployeeMother {
        private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

        @Autowired
        protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        private Employee empJohnDoe;

        /**
         * 
         * @return returns an admin user with username djohn
         */
        public Employee getEmpJohnDoe() {
            empJohnDoe = new Employee();
            empJohnDoe.setUserName("djohn");

            Role role = new Role();
            //as only the id of the role is not nullable I set it as 1 = admin
            role.setId(new Long(1));
            empJohnDoe.setRole(role);
            empJohnDoe.setCompany(new Company());

            Identification identity = new Identification();
            identity.setFirstName("John");
            identity.setLastName("Doe");
            identity.setContact(new Contact());
            empJohnDoe.setIdentity(identity);

            return empJohnDoe;
        }

        public void setEmpJohnDoe(Employee empJohnDoe) {
            this.empJohnDoe = empJohnDoe;
        }

        /**
         * Important! this insert does not cover some details of the Employee:
         * It inserts null in the following columns:
         * pswd,
         * image,
         * cnt_id, - should be a list of associated contacts
         * salt,
         * is_active,
         * default_work_hours
         * The insert in TAB_IDENTIFICATIONS triggers TRIG_IDNT that inserts stuff in an audit table
         * For it to work we need to register a logged user
         * That's why we call PAC_SECURITY.PRO_SETCTX('emp_user_name','adminUserName'); (i used an admin)
         * I preferred doing this rather than inserting djohn in TAB_EMPLOYEES, 
         * registering djohn as logged then inserting an identity in TAB_IDENTIFICATIONS
         * and then updating djohn with the new identity
         * @param emp - Employee to be inserted
         */
        public void insert(Employee emp){
            jdbcTemplate.update("call PAC_SECURITY.PRO_SETCTX('emp_user_name','adminUserName')");

            Long identityId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select max(ti.ID)+1 from tab_identifications ti", Long.class);
            emp.getIdentity().setId(identityId);

            jdbcTemplate.update(""+
                "   insert into tab_identifications ("+
                "       id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, cnp, ci_char, ci_number, birth_date, invalidity,"+
                "       cas_name, ci_issue_date, ci_issuer, cnt_id"+
                "   )" +
                "   values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                new Object[]{emp.getIdentity().getId(), emp.getIdentity().getFirstName(), emp.getIdentity().getMiddleName(),
                             emp.getIdentity().getLastName(), emp.getIdentity().getCnp(), emp.getIdentity().getIdCardSerial(),
                             emp.getIdentity().getIdCardNumber(), emp.getIdentity().getBirthDate(), 
                             emp.getIdentity().getInvalidity(), emp.getIdentity().getCAS(), emp.getIdentity().getCiIssueDate(),
                             emp.getIdentity().getCiIssuer(), emp.getIdentity().getContact().getId()}
            );      

            Long id = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select max(te.ID)+1 from tab_employees te", Long.class);
            emp.setId(id);
            jdbcTemplate.update(""+
                "   insert into tab_employees (id, user_name, code, pswd, idnt_id, role_id, comp_id, image, "+
                "       hire_date, cnt_id, salt, is_expired, is_active, default_work_hours "+
                "   )" +
                "   values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                new Object[]{emp.getId(), emp.getUserName(), emp.getCode(), null, emp.getIdentity().getId(),
                             emp.getRole().getId(), emp.getCompany().getId(), null, emp.getHireDate(),
                             null, null, emp.getIsExpired(), null, null
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

**HomeEmployeeServiceImplIntegrationTest:**

```
    package com.employee.service.impl;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

    import com.domain.vo.Document;
    import com.domain.vo.Employee;
    import com.domain.objMother.EmployeeMother;
    import com.employee.service.HomeEmployeeService;
    import com.util.annotations.TransactionalDevTest;

    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @TransactionalDevTest
    public class HomeEmployeeServiceImplIntegrationTest {

        @Autowired
        protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        @Autowired
        HomeEmployeeService homeEmployeeService;

        @Autowired
        EmployeeMother empMother;

        Employee empJohnDoe;

        @Before
        public void beforeEachTest() throws Exception {
            empJohnDoe = empMother.getEmpJohnDoe();
            empMother.insert(empJohnDoe);
        }

        /**
         * You should not be able to add a document with the same name
         * <code>uploadDocument</code> should not insert the document if it has the same name 
         */
        @Test
        public void shouldNotBeAbleToAddSameDoc(){
            Document doc = new Document();
            Long id = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select max(td.ID)+1 from tab_documents td", Long.class);
            doc.setId(id);
            doc.setFileName("SameOldDocument");

            homeEmployeeService.uploadDocument(empJohnDoe.getIdentity(), doc);

            id = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select max(td.ID)+1 from tab_documents td", Long.class);
            doc.setId(id);
            homeEmployeeService.uploadDocument(empJohnDoe.getIdentity(), doc);

            Long docNo = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(id) from tab_documents td where doc_file_name = '" + doc.getFileName() + "'", Long.class);

            if(docNo.compareTo(new Long(2)) == 0){
                assertEquals("I was able to add a document twice with the same name!", new Long(1), docNo);
            }
            else{
                assertEquals("Something went wrong when adding two documents with the same name! The document should be added once or twice, but the result is different!", new Long(1), docNo);
            }
        }
    }
```